# input scanner in Java

Tags: java, arrays, input

what im trying to do is read 3 files, and simply store them in an array called Student, and print out the files read using readIRstudent, readIR101 and readIR102. My problem is when i execute the code only the first readIRstudent actually prints out in my test class, and i cant get the array to work either. Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by Lewis on 28/03/2015.
 */
public class Task2 {

public Scanner input;
int reg;
double ir101,ir102l;
double aggregate;
String student_name;

public void openIRstud()throws Exception{
    JFileChooser IRstudchooser = new JFileChooser();
    if(IRstudchooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File inFile = IRstudchooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        System.out.println("IRstudents file read successfully.");
    }
}
public void openIR101()throws Exception{
    JFileChooser IR101chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if(IR101chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File inFile = IR101chooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(inFile);
        System.out.println("IR101 file read successfully.");
    }
}
public void openIR102()throws Exception{
    JFileChooser IR102chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if(IR102chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        java.io.File inFile1 = IR102chooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(inFile1);
        System.out.println("IR102 file read successfully.");
    }
}
public void readIRstud (){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String irstudid = input.next();
        String irname = input.next();
        System.out.printf(" %s %s\n", irstudid, irname);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
public void readIR101 (){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String ir101studid = input.next();
        String ir101mark = input.next();
        System.out.printf(" %s %s\n", ir101studid, ir101mark);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
public void readIR102 (){
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String ir102studid = input.next();
        String ir102mark = input.next();
        System.out.printf(" %s %s\n", ir102studid, ir102mark);
    }
    System.out.println("Complete.");
}
public void Student(){
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        Student e = new Student();
        e.reg = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
        e.ir101 = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[1]);
        students.add(e);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Also the section   ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>(); says "diamond types are not supported in this language level" how do i fix that ?

Comment: To fix that just replace this line with `ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();`

Comment: try `ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();`  placing `Student` in second diamond

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't print out anything although it does contain methods that would print if called. To see why something isn't printed one has to see the code that's supposed to do it.

Comment: where is your main method? or a constructor? the flow of this class is not clear...